# download file from remote server asp.net

Tags: asp.net, httpwebrequest, download

I am trying to download file from a file hosting server, using my username and password through my own website.

I already achieve the possibility to connect and download the file, with the code attached below.
my problem is this code doesn't support resume of download and my download manager isn't able to open more then one connection to the remote site ,so the speed is very low(the remote site Of course is supporting those features)
my main goal is to let me download this file with full speed and with the ability to resume the download in any Second.

this is the code

```
//the login method

    ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
    string url = "RemoteServerLoginPage/loginPage";
    string postVariables = "id=myIdToTheServer";
    postVariables += "&password=MyPasswordToTheServer";
    // create the POST request
    HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();

    webRequest.CookieContainer = cookies;
    webRequest.Method = "POST";
    webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    webRequest.ContentLength = postVariables.Length;
    byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postVariables);
    Stream newStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream();
    // Send the request
    newStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);


    HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();


    using (Stream stream = resp.GetResponseStream())
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
        String responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();

    }



//after login get the file with thr right cookies

    string url2 = "UrlOfRemoteServerFileAdress/filename.rar";
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url2);
   req.CookieContainer = cookies;
    HttpWebResponse resp2 = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();


    ////Initialize the output stream
    Response.Clear();
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition:", "attachment; filename=myfile.rar");
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length:", "bytes");
    Response.AppendHeader("Connection:", "Keep-Alive");
    Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    Response.AppendHeader("AcceptRanges", resp2.ContentLength.ToString());

    const int BufferLength = 4 * 1024 * 1024;
    byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[BufferLength];
    Stream rs = req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();

    int len = 0;
    while ((len = rs.Read(byteBuffer, 0, byteBuffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        if (len < BufferLength)
        {
            Response.BinaryWrite(byteBuffer.Take(len).ToArray());
        }
        else
        {
            Response.BinaryWrite(byteBuffer);
        }
        Response.Flush();


    }
```